# pkg-config won't run

Tags: macos, terminal, install

I'm trying to fix a path-related problem with glib, but as part of this another problem has appeared:

```
brew install pkg-config
Warning: pkg-config 0.29.2 is already installed and up-to-date
```

Ok, good, so:

```
pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config: Permission denied
```

Right, right...

```
sudo pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
sudo: pkg-config: command not found
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

**Update:** one of the commands fixed things:

```
pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
-I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.3/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.62.3/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.43/include
```

Comment: Adding the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/pkg-config` and (assuming it's a symlink) the link target might help. Also running `brew doctor` (and resolving any issues) or `brew reinstall pkg-config` should fix a lot of potential issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn’t sudo anything brew related for installs in /usr/local and use one Unix user only to manage homebrew. The only exception is some initial setup or remediation steps when you are explicitly instructed by the tool to use `sudo`

What’s happening is some permissions (using sudo likely) went bad in /usr/local so you might need to revert them.

```
brew doctor
```

The above command is designed to find and help you fix many of the common ways people can have issues installing packages so I would start there. Also run a command to see what leaves you need in case you have to clean up and remove all the brewed items and reinstall one by one once your permissions are set.

```
brew leaves
```

Comment: One of the commands here appears to have fixed it. Updated